# No able to center Elements in the DIV

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

Hi I am having trouble centering elements on mobile.
Website: https://dachsteinkaffee.myshopify.com/

I have set the `margin-right` of elements `col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4` to `0px` but it looks like the margin is still appearing.

Tried to apply text-align:center to the class .img-box. But it did not help.

I have tried different options like this that did not work:

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #home-spotlight-1541414200176 .container-fluid .spotlight-3-blocks {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row spotlight-3-blocks">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="spotlight-item">
            <div class="img-box">
                <a href="" class="animate-scale">
                    <img
                        data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/1786/8231/files/Dachstein-Kaffee-Morgengruss-Startseite_800x800_crop_center.jpg?v=1621598467"
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/1786/8231/files/Dachstein-Kaffee-Morgengruss-Startseite_800x800_crop_center.jpg?v=1621598467"
                        alt="Dachsteinkaffee"
                        itemprop="logo"
                        class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded"
                        data-sizes="auto"
                        sizes="370px"
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="content spotlight-inner">
                <h3 class="title"><span> MORGENGRUSS </span></h3>
                <p class="des"><span> Der Filterkaffee eignet sich nicht nur für Frühaufsteher... </span></p>
                <a href="" class="spotlight-button btn"> <span> ZUM KAFFEE </span> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First, in your demo code here, there is no `#home-spotlight-1541414200176 .container fluid` so it won't work here.

Then this margin right is auto generated to fill the empty as your image is not enought large to cover the whole space.

Just apply `text-align:center` to your class `.img-box`:

### DEMO:

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .img-box {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row spotlight-3-blocks">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="spotlight-item">
            <div class="img-box">
                <a href="" class="animate-scale">
                    <img
                        data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/1786/8231/files/Dachstein-Kaffee-Morgengruss-Startseite_800x800_crop_center.jpg?v=1621598467"
                        src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/1786/8231/files/Dachstein-Kaffee-Morgengruss-Startseite_800x800_crop_center.jpg?v=1621598467"
                        alt="Dachsteinkaffee"
                        itemprop="logo"
                        class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded"
                        data-sizes="auto"
                        sizes="370px"
                    />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="content spotlight-inner">
                <h3 class="title"><span> MORGENGRUSS </span></h3>
                <p class="des"><span> Der Filterkaffee eignet sich nicht nur für Frühaufsteher... </span></p>
                <a href="" class="spotlight-button btn"> <span> ZUM KAFFEE </span> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for you help unfortunatelly the items are still not centered. This is the website link if it helps https://dachsteinkaffee.myshopify.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this
there was an issue in `#home-spotlight-1541414200176 .container-fluid`

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {.spotlight-3-blocks {
text-align: center;
}}
```

```html
<div class="row spotlight-3-blocks">
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="spotlight-item">
        <div class="img-box">
            <a href="" class="animate-scale">
                <img
                    data-src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/1786/8231/files/Dachstein-Kaffee-Morgengruss-Startseite_800x800_crop_center.jpg?v=1621598467"
                    src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0571/1786/8231/files/Dachstein-Kaffee-Morgengruss-Startseite_800x800_crop_center.jpg?v=1621598467"
                    alt="Dachsteinkaffee"
                    itemprop="logo"
                    class="lazyautosizes lazyloaded"
                    data-sizes="auto"
                    sizes="370px"
                />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content spotlight-inner">
            <h3 class="title"><span> MORGENGRUSS </span></h3>
            <p class="des"><span> Der Filterkaffee eignet sich nicht nur für Frühaufsteher... </span></p>
            <a href="" class="spotlight-button btn"> <span> ZUM KAFFEE </span> </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi it did not work. This is my website if it helps https://dachsteinkaffee.myshopify.com/

Comment: @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)
.spotlight-2-blocks>.col-md-6, .spotlight-3-blocks>.col-md-6
do max-width:100% or something else its error in max-width